# Why I can not set the platform to x64 in debug configuration in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, visual-studio-debugging

I have a c++ project in VS 2012.

I can set the release to x64 and it works well.

But I am not able to do the same for debug. In build configuration, when I change the platform of my application to x64, after I exit from the build manager it changes to win32.

The entries in my solution is as follow:

```
{AD00C39B-4CDE-4A88-BA72-C4FD9EC53D2C}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
{AD00C39B-4CDE-4A88-BA72-C4FD9EC53D2C}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
{AD00C39B-4CDE-4A88-BA72-C4FD9EC53D2C}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
{AD00C39B-4CDE-4A88-BA72-C4FD9EC53D2C}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
{AD00C39B-4CDE-4A88-BA72-C4FD9EC53D2C}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
{AD00C39B-4CDE-4A88-BA72-C4FD9EC53D2C}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
{AD00C39B-4CDE-4A88-BA72-C4FD9EC53D2C}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
{AD00C39B-4CDE-4A88-BA72-C4FD9EC53D2C}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
```

If I change the debug platform to x64, it revert back to win32 after I run vs and it saves the solution.

What do I need to do to make sure that my debug system works in x64?

Comment: Probably you are using the wrong version of the .net framework in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Even when debugging locally Visual Studio 2012 uses remote debugging to connect between WOW64 and the 64-bit application on the same computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms184681.aspx), so make sure that you have installed remote debugging, [here is how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the platform to x64 inside Visual Studio or with a text editor? If the latter is the case you should probably have a look at the `vcxproj` file to make sure it actually contains the definitions for `Debug|x64`.

Comment: I did both with the same result. How can I add debug|x64 to project (vcxproj)?

Comment: First of all: Never do this without a backup! What you need is an editor that shows a decent view of the XML structure of the vcxproj file. I suggest Notepad++. Open the file and locate e.g. the release|x64 node under <ProjectConfiguration> and duplicate it into a debug|x64 node. Then go through the other nodes and look for those with a release|x64 condition in their attributes and duplicate those as well, setting debug|x64 as the condition. Once done you'll have a debug|x64 config that is identical your release|x64. Change the settings to values appropriates for debug configs after that.

Comment: Of course a potentially quicker option is to remove the Release|x64 project config and both solution configs, then create new solution configs and have Visual Studio generate the project configs to go with it. However, that way you will loose the settings made to the Release|x64.